# how to setup oracle weblogic server 11g 10.3.6 in STS Eclipse Neon.3 (4.6.3)

Tags: eclipse, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

Hi I want to deploy a j2ee application on Weblogic 11g 10.3.5

I have installed weblogic 11g 10.3.5 on my windows 7 machine.

I am trying to add weblogic server in STS using below:

Window -> Preferences -> Server -> Runtime environment -> Add -> Oracle.

Here I am not getting the option of Weblogic 11g 10.3.5 to add.

I read that we need to install Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse.

I tried to install it from this link:

http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/luna

But from here only support for weblogic server 12c is being installed.

Please let me know the site url or the steps needed to add weblogic 10.3.5 server as Runtime server in Spring Tool Suite(STS)

Answer (score 1):

I know it can be this can be late answer but it can be useful to others.
You can refer the guide at:

> https://blogs.oracle.com/weblogicserver/weblogic-server-in-eclipse-ide-for-java-ee-developers

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question according to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer since link-only answers are likely to be flagged and deleted. Hint: Quote a bit the website, explain why it is a solution.